# Auditing .csv files via data-frames to a database, how can I ensure that only that day's data is being added?

Tags: python, mysql, database, raspberry-pi

I am working on a project with various sensors. I will be sending data from the sensor system at midnight each night. I want the data from that day only to be added. Here is the problem: The sensors are running 24/7 and are outputting data into csv files that are stored on a Raspberry-Pi. Some are outputting data every 30 minutes, some every hour, and some every 5 minutes.

My question: How do I, via python, ensure that the dataframes that are inputted into the database reflect only data from that day? I understand some of the syntax from mysql that would allow this, such as select(MAX from...) but that I think doesn't apply here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I found a method, I will post it here because I feel like it's a little bit of a dodgy way of doing it.

```
#Use
df.to_sql(name='tdr',con=engine,if_exists='replace',index=False) 
#Instead of 
df.to_sql(name='tdr',con=engine,if_exists='append',index=False)
```

This replaces all of the data in said file, and repopulates it with the previous sensor data as well as the new rows in the csv file.